# How does Kindle Fire OS systemversion map to Fire OS and android versions

Tags: android, version, kindle

I have a Kindle Fire that has a "systemversion" of 7.4.8.user_... installed on it. How does this version number map to the Fire OS version numbers and on what android version is it based on?

Does anybody know a link where a mapping is provided that maps systemversion, fire os version and android version for all versions?

Answer (score 1):

You can find its exact version by connecting the device via adb with developer options enabled in it. Usually 7th Generation Kindle devices run KitKat and 8th Generation Kindle devices run Lollipop.

Check this page out for more details,
[Amazon Kindle Device Specifications](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/devices/kindle-fire/specifications/01-device-and-feature-specifications)